# Equilibrium Solution in Solving a Linear ODE using an Integrating Factor

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

### Problem

I've stumbled upon this differential equation during the second week of my ODE class in university:

$$ y' - \frac{2}{t+1}y = (t+1)^2$$

And I solved it using the exact procedure in the "Attempt" section below. I checked my work and indeed got the right answer, but as I was solving the problem, I was having difficulty discerning the domain of the function and the equilibrium solutions that arise in the midst of solving such a problem.

I believe there are no equilibrium solutions to take into account in this case, but my main goal of asking this question is for the answerer to outline **when to check for equilibrium solutions**, **how to go about doing it**, and providing **best practices for constraining** both the dependent and independent variables, as well as constants found along the way.

### Attempt

Here is my attempt at the solution:

$$ y' - \frac{2}{t+1}y = (t+1)^2 $$

$ t \neq -1 $ is implicitly assumed.

$$ \mu(t) = e^{\int p(t)dt} $$
$$ p(t) = -\frac{2}{t+1} $$
$$ \int p(t)dt = \int -\frac{2}{t+1}dt = -2ln|t+1|+C_1 $$

for $ C_1 \in \mathbb R $.

$$ \mu(t) = e^{-2ln|t+1| + C_1} = e^{C_1}e^{ln|t+1|^{-2}} $$

Let $ C_2 = e^{C_1}$ for $ C_2 \in \mathbb R $, $ C_2 \gt 0 $.

$$ \mu(t) = C_2 e^{ln(\frac{1}{(t+1)^2})} $$
$$ \mu(t) = C_2 \frac{1}{(t+1)^2} $$

Multiplying both sides by the **integrating factor** $ \mu(t) $,

$$ C_2 \frac{1}{(t+1)^2} y' - C_2 \frac{1}{(t+1)^2} \frac{2}{(t+1)}y = C_2 \frac{1}{(t+1)^2} (t+1)^2 $$
$$ (t + 1)^{-2} y' - 2(t+1)^{-3}y = 1 $$
$$ ((t+1)^{-2}y)' = 1 $$
$$ (t+1)^{-2}y = \int 1 dt $$
$$ (t+1)^{-2}y = t + C_3 $$

for $ C_3 \in \mathbb R $. Dividing both sides by $ \mu(t) $ we get,

$$ \frac{(t+1)^2}{C_2 (t+1)^2} y = \frac{(t+1)^2(t+C_3)}{C_2} $$
$$ y = (t+1)^2(t+C_3) $$

### Notes

I'd love the answerer to identify where to check for equilibrium cases in this situation, as well as answer the above bolded questions. I understand equilibrium solutions are to be checked when variables may be separated to solve a differential equation, but I'd love to know all the other cases and have that part be elaborated to me.

Here's the direction field for $ y' = f(t,y) $:

[image: Direction Field]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's a vertical asymptote at $ t = -1 $ (updated the question with an image of the direction field).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any non-autonomous system $y' = f(t,y)$, equilibria are found as horizontal asymptotes of the solution $y(t)$. If $t$ represents a "forward-time" variable, then we say $t > t_0$, where $y(t_0)$ is the initial condition, and only look at $\lim\limits_{t\to+\infty} y(t)$.

ex: $y' =-ty \Rightarrow y = y_0e^{-t^2/2}$. Taking $t\to\pm\infty$ gives $y = 0$. Alternatively, $y' = -ty = 0 \Rightarrow t=0$ or $y=0$, and since we assume that $t$ is not always $0$, $y=0$ must be an equilibrium.

---

In an autonomous system $y' = g(y)$ which doesn't directly depend on $t$, then equilibria are found by solving the equation $y' = 0$, or equivalently $g(y) = 0$, for $y$. This doesn't involve solving the equation, which (among many other features) makes equilibrium analysis much more important for autonomous systems than non-autonomous ones.

ex: $y'= y(1-y) = 0 \Rightarrow y = 0$ or $y = 1$ are equilibria.

Comment: Aha! I'm starting to understand it. Do you mind supplementing an example of obtaining an equilibrium solution for a non-autonomous system?

Comment: I've added a simple example of each type.

Comment: That clears everything up for me. Thanks for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

An equilibrium solution is one in which $y’=0$ is independent of $t$.  In this problem, if you set the derivative equals to $0$ and solve for $y$, any solution will depend on $t$, so there is no equilibrium point.